# Error: [MobX] Cannot apply 'observable' to 'Store@user': Field not found

Tags: typescript, mobx, state-management

I have a Store:

```
class Store {
  user!: User;

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      user: observable,
      setUser: action
    });
  }
  
  setUser = (user: User | undefined) => this.user = user;
}
```

And I'm getting this error:
`Error: [MobX] Cannot apply 'observable' to 'Store@user': Field not found.`

`User` is a custom object, should I treat him differently (observable wise)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 19):

[By default](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations) `make(Auto)Observable` only supports properties that are already defined, so you need to define `user` inside constructor or make it nullable like that: `user: User | null = null`.

Alternatively you might want to try to reconfigure [how class properties initialisation works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier), using `useDefineForClassFields` TS compiler flag:

```js
"compilerOptions": {
  "useDefineForClassFields": true
},
```