# Mobx async example does not render result after action

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

### You can look at the issue via codesandbox

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-frog-m2s7h

### Context

I am trying to fetch some data and populate some variable and render the value in React, essentially following the documentation await/async + runInAction example: https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#asynchronous-actions

However, when the data is fetched, React actually does not re-render. However, if you edit the text in there(i.e. change `hi` to `his` or whatever, then you see the correct value appear.

### Problem

What exactly am I doing wrong with the data fetching? Why isn't the observable value not being re-rendered correctly when its been assigned a value after some data has been fetched?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: \[MobX\] Cannot apply 'observable' to 'Store@user': Field not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266810/error-mobx-cannot-apply-observable-to-storeuser-field-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple mistake. MobX can not compare data of `title` to something that dosent exist. Stuff should have default value of some sort, even a `null`. hence in a constructor you need to define `title` default value like

```
constructor() {
    this.title = [],
    makeAutoObservable(this);
}
```

or, if you wish, even `null`

```
constructor() {
    this.title = null,
    makeAutoObservable(this);
}
```

Basiclaly, whenever you create some observable variable in a store - you need to define its default value in a constructor above `makeAutoObservable`.

Here, a forked project of yours  with juswt this 1 line change to make it work https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-noether-fnhjw

Answer (score 2):

This is actually one of the limitations of Mobx.

From the [docs](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations):

> make(Auto)Observable only supports properties that are already defined. Make sure your compiler configuration is correct, or as workaround, that a value is assigned to all properties before using make(Auto)Observable. Without correct configuration, fields that are declared but not initialized (like in class X { y; }) will not be picked up correctly.

Just initialize the title `this.title=undefined` and it will work.