# Mobx observer component not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, mobx

I am using Mobx in my react app for global state. It has been working fantastic and exactly as expected until now. I am storing the mouse position in an SVG element in the store and hoping to utilize this state in a number of components. I can tell the state is changing correctly by logging inside the store, but for some reason my CrossHairs component is not re-rendering despite being wrapped in an observer HOC and featuring dereferenced store values. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Store:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx';
import { PriceDataStore } from './_priceDataStore';
import { groupByFunction } from './utils/rxjs/groupByFunction';
import { TradePlanStore } from './_tradePlanStore';

export class WebsocketStore {
  websocketSubject = webSocket('ws://localhost:8080/socket');
  chartSubject;

  priceDataStore;
  tradePlanStore;
  mouseCoordinates;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
    this.priceDataStore = new PriceDataStore(this);
    this.tradePlanStore = new TradePlanStore(this);
    this.chartSubject = groupByFunction(
      'messageType',
      'getChart',
      this.websocketSubject
    );
    this.mouseCoordinates = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    };
  }

  sendWebsocketMessage = (msg) => {
    this.websocketSubject.next(msg);
  };

  updateCoordinates = (coordinates) => {
    this.mouseCoordinates = { x: coordinates[0], y: coordinates[1] };
  };
}
const WebsocketContext = createContext(null);
export const useWebsocketStore = () => useContext(WebsocketContext);

export const WebSocketProvider = ({ store, children }) => {
  return (
    <WebsocketContext.Provider value={store}>
      {children}
    </WebsocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

WebSocketProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.any,
  store: PropTypes.any,
};
```

**Place where state is being changed, this seems to be working:**

```
const websocketStore = useWebsocketStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    select(zoomRef.current)
      .on('mouseenter', () => {
        setShowCrossHairs(true);
      })
      .on('mousemove', (event) => {
        const coordinates = pointer(event);
        websocketStore.updateCoordinates(coordinates);
      })
      .on('mouseleave', () => {
        setShowCrossHairs(false);
      });
  }, [websocketStore.updateCoordinates]);
```

**Component that is not triggered to re-render on mouseCoordinates state change in store despite being wrapped in observer and dereferencing mouseCoordinates values.**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { select, pointer } from 'd3';
import { colors } from '../../../../../../colorVars';
import { useWebsocketStore } from '../../../../../../stores/websocketStore/websocketStore';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';

const ChartCrossHairs = observer(({
  size,
  bottomPadding,
  showCrossHairs,
}) => {
  const websocketStore = useWebsocketStore();
  const x = websocketStore.mouseCoordinates.x;
  const y = websocketStore.mouseCoordinates.y;


  return (
    <g>
      {showCrossHairs && (
        <>
          <line
            strokeDasharray="1, 1"
            x1={0}
            x2={size}
            y1={y}
            y2={y}
            stroke={colors.white}
          />
          <line
            strokeDasharray="1, 1"
            y1={0}
            y2={size + bottomPadding}
            x1={x}
            x2={x}
            stroke={colors.white}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </g>
  );
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: \[MobX\] Cannot apply 'observable' to 'Store@user': Field not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266810/error-mobx-cannot-apply-observable-to-storeuser-field-not-found)

Comment: I don't believe so. It appears my state is updating fine. For some reason my component is not tracking the changes properly and not triggering re-rending when the state changes.

Comment: So you tried to move `makeAutoObservable` to the end and it didn't hepl?